# gevent-socketio and namespaces

Tags: namespaces, gevent

Has anybody tried to use gevent-socketio with a namespace other than the default value ie socket.io?  I really want to use a different namespace but I just cant get the sample (chat) program to work.  Any tips on how to configure namespaces would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "namespace" you are talking about (socket.io) is now called "resource": https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/839d92c4d736f00a1ca886d4d98f027981e47476/socketio/server.py#L58

Comment: Yes thank you.  I contributed a patch to bring clarity to socket.io  https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/commits/master/socketio/server.py?author=vivekhub

Answer (score 1):

I used gevent-socketio before they introduced namepsaces. The message send on the wire simply looks like this:

```
{'namespace': { 'data': 'value', .... }}
```

It's pretty easy to write something yourself that on client and server side checks what is the first value of namespace and call the appropriate handlers.
So now I just use the normal gevent-websocket libary. ws4py will also work just fine.